# Nodejs pass variable from router file to another router file

Tags: node.js, express, router, express-router

i need to pass a variable called `path` from router file `lessonsRouter.js` to another router file `lessons.js`

**My folder structure**

```
routes
|
+--lessons.js
|
+--lessonsRouter.js
```

**lessonsRouter.js**

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const lessons = require('./lessons');

router.get('/*/([A-Z][a-z]+)/README.md', (req, res) => {
  const path = req.url; // the variable that i need to pass to lessons.js router

// ignore next three lines
  const pathSeparate = req.url.split('/');
  const LessonTopic = pathSeparate[1].toLowerCase()
  const LessonName = pathSeparate[2].match(/[A-Z][a-z]+/g).join('-').toLowerCase();

  res.locals.path = path;
  res.redirect(`/lessons/${LessonTopic}/${LessonName}`);
});

router.use('/:topic/:name', lessons);

module.exports = router;
```

**lessons.js**

```js
const router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // i want to use variable path from lessonsRouter.js here

});
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that you have your dependency/import direction wrong. `lessons` should import from `lessonsRouter`. But if you really want it this way, then you can export a function to which you can pass the path *once you have it*.

lessonsRouter.js

```
const lessons = require('./lessons');

router.get('/*/([A-Z][a-z]+)/README.md', (req, res) => {
  const path = req.url; // the variable that i need to pass to lessons.js router
  lessons(path);
  ...
});
```

lessons.js

```
module.exports = (path) => {
  router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(path);
  });
};
```

Comment: that give me an error 
`TypeError: Cannot create property 'next' on string '/Gdscript/BeforeStarting/README.md'`

that path it handles by the regex part

Comment: `lessons(path);` it is legal ?
i now have 2 `module.exports` in `lessons.js`

Comment: No, not in addition, too. What I show should be *all* you shoul dhave in lessonsjs.

Comment: no, server is hanging, even if i do `res.send('anything')` in `lessons.js`